# .bashrc/.profile is not loaded on new tmux session (or window) -- why?

Tags: tmux

When tmux starts or opens a new window, it does not load my `.profile` or `.bashrc`.  I end up typing `. ~/.bashrc` every time.  Is there a way to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Yes, at the end of your `.bash_profile`, put the line:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

This automatically sources the rc file under those circumstances where it would normally only process the profile.

The rules as to when `bash` runs certain files are complicated, and depend on the type of shell being started (login/non-login, interactive or not, and so forth), along with command line arguments and environment variables.

You can see them in the `man bash` output, just look for `INVOCATION` - you'll probably need some time to digest and decode it though :-)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that on some systems, .bashrc calls .bash_profile.

Comment: Let me correct myself: systems do not have .bashrc calling .bash_profile, but you need to make sure you're not doing yourself.

Comment: @Honza, that would be a most unusual setup since it's almost always the other way around. Someone could certainly arrange to do it that way but we'd have to question their sanity :-)

Comment: Indeed, it turned out that I have arranged to do it that way (and forgot about it). You're welcome to question my sanity... ;)

Comment: what about tmux under Linux? I want to run `gnome-terminal -e tmux` so that tmux automatically starts when I run the command, but neither my `.profile` nor my `.bashrc` are sourced. (`.profile` is automatically sourced when `gnome-terminal` is run, however this is not the case when a `tmux` is passed in after `-e`.) Any way to fix this ion Linux? `gnome-terminal -e "tmux new bash"` doesn't work and `.bashrc` is sourced in `.profile` as it should be - as I said `.profile` is automatically sourced when run normally.

Comment: @dylnmc, if you have a different question (while related, it does seem to be different enough to warrant difference), it's probably better to ask it as a new question. That way, you'll get more exposure.

Comment: I thought that was the question... `.bashrc/.profile is not loaded on new tmux session (or window) — why?`

Comment: @dylnmc Under Linux I created a `~/.bash_profile`, included `. ~/.bashrc` and setup my gnome-terminal to run `tmux attach` (session is created in tmux.config) and it is working. Take a look at the image from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29794590/1814970

Comment: It do seem to scramble my vim syntax highlighting.

Comment: @infostacker I saw that later on. I actually answered that a few answers down :)

Answer (score 22):

Running bash explicitly worked for me, by adding this line to my ~/.tmux.conf file:

```
set-option -g default-command "exec /bin/bash"
```

Comment: This worked for me! However, you don't need the "exec" part. I added the following line to my `~/.tmux.conf `: `set -g default-command "/bin/bash"`. Thanks mate.

Comment: But, do you have any idea why is this happening? I suddenly noticed this after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.2. This is the only difference I can think of. Also, I noticed that some of the configurations broke and I had to comply to some new syntax (seems like tmux got updated as well, but I don't remember the tmux version I previously used to verify).

Answer (score 14):

Former answers provided solutions but didn't explain the reason. Here it is.

This is related to the Bash init files. By default, `~/.bashrc` is used in an **interactive, non-login** shell. It won't be sourced in a login shell. Tmux uses a **login shell** by default. Hence, shells started by tmux skip `~/.bashrc`.

> `default-command` shell-command
>
> The default is an empty string, **which instructs tmux to create a login shell** using the value of the `default-shell` option.

Init files for Bash,

1. login mode:

   1. `/etc/profile`
   2. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only first one that exists)
2. **interactive** **non-login**:

   1. `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
   2. `~/.bashrc`
3. non-interactive:

   1. source file in `$BASH_ENV`

The weird interactive, non-login loading requirement confuses people in other situations as well. The **best solution** is to change the loading requirement of `~/.bashrc` as **interactive only**, which is exactly what some distros, like Ubuntu, are doing.

```
# write content below into ~/.profile, or ~/.bash_profile

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This should be the solution you desire. And I recommend every Bash user setup this in the profile.

References

- [Unix Shell Initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization)
- `man tmux`

Comment: that was an excellent explanation and finally helped me after reading a bunch of things trying to understand all this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

From this thread:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=124274

seems using `.bash_profile` would work.

Comment: The link just gives the advise to use: `$echo case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac >> .bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is the following:

- Create a `.bash_profile` file if you don't have one in `~`
- At the end of `.bash_profile` put `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.profile`
- Restart tmux.

The issue should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solutions so far didn't work for me. The solution that ended up working for me can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320496/286380).

In short, `tmux` windows/sessions use a login shell which looks for a `~/.profile` among other files when it starts.

What I wanted was to have zsh start with each new `tmux` window so I put `exec zsh` at the bottom of my `~/.profile`.