# How can I make TMUX be active whenever I start a new shell session?

Tags: shell, session, terminal, tmux

Instead of having to type `tmux` every time, **how could I have `tmux` always be used for new session windows**?

So if I have no terminal windows open and then I open one, how can that first session be in `tmux`?

Seems like a `.bashrc` sort of thing perhaps?

Comment: `Ctrl-b c` will create a new window.

Comment: thanks, I mean if I'm not in a terminal window at all.

Comment: What operating system do you use? (And what terminal emulator?)

Comment: terminal = default terminal program, plus tmux

Answer (score 68, accepted):

*warning* **this can now 'corrupt' (make it unable to open a terminal window - which is not good!) your Ubuntu logins.  Use with extreme caution and make sure you have a second admin account on the computer that you can log into in case you have the same problems I did.  See my *other* answer for more details and a different approach.**

Given that warning, the simplest solution can be to append the `tmux` invocation to the end of your `.bashrc`, e.g.

```
alias g="grep"
alias ls="ls --color=auto"

# ...other stuff...

if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

Note that the `exec` means that the bash process which starts when you open the terminal is *replaced* by `tmux`, so `Ctrl-B D` (i.e. disconnect from tmux) actually closes the window, instead of returning to the original bash process, which is probably the behaviour you want?

Also, the `if` statement is required (it detects if the current bash window is in a tmux process already) otherwise each time you start tmux, the contained bash process will attempt to start its own tmux session, leading to an infinite number of nested tmuxen which can be, err, quite annoying (that said, it looks cool).

---

However, there is a very small risk this can make `bash` behave in a way that other programs don't expect, since running bash can possibly cause it to turn into a tmux process, so it might be better to modify how you start your terminal emulator.

I use a small executable shell script `~/bin/terminal` (with `~/bin` in `$PATH`, so it is found automatically) that looks a bit like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gnome-terminal -e tmux
```

(I don't use gnome-terminal, so you might have to remove the `exec`, I'm not sure.)

Now whenever you run the `terminal` scipt you have a terminal with tmux. You can add this to your menu/desktop/keyboard shortcuts to replace the default terminal.

(This approach also allows you to more easily customise other things about the terminal emulator later, if you ever desire.)

Comment: How does one get around the fact that this can create a ton of sessions if you are opening/closing terminal windows frequently?

Comment: Is it note better to put the line at the start of the file? If the process is replaced, then all changes made by the `.bashrc` are lost. Then the `.bashrc` is sourced again when `tmux` spawns `bash` again. Why run it twice!?

Comment: `exec gnome-terminal -e tmux` FTW

Comment: What if you don't want to replace bash? Remove exec?

Comment: In Fedora 25, I was getting a login loop when I had `exec tmux` in my `.bashrc`.  Since I had already set `Super`+`C` as a keyboard shortcut to launch terminal, I added `-e tmux` to the shortcut command to easily start a tmux session.  Specifically, I have the shortcut set to execute `gnome-terminal --window --full-screen -e tmux`

Comment: I installed tilda for ubutu as a backup terminal just in case of emergency :) Thanks for the warning

Answer (score 17):

My original, accepted answer, stopped working on my Ubuntu14 system after a recent upgrade.

Using either

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && command -v tmux > /dev/null && TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

or

```
[ $TERM != "screen" ] && TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

would stop me from being able to even login.  I was only able to resolve this due to having a second admin login on the computer.

The fix for me on Ubuntu (and in osx too) was to change my terminal program to actually run tmux instead, i.e.

[image]

I still have

```
[ `uname -s` != Linux ] && exec tmux
```

as my last `.bashrc` line but that his only for my Mac OSX systems now.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to have a single tmux session,  put the following in your ~/.bashrc for **bash** or ~/.zshrc for **zsh**:

```
tmux attach &> /dev/null

if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

The *`tmux attach` line* is to make sure if there is a session it attaches to and if there was no session you will not get the warning about "*no session*".

Comment: I use `ps` to check if there is a tmux process.

Answer (score 9):

For me, I would love my tmux to be started every time I shell onto my remote machine, and when I detach or exit from tmux, the connection should be closed automatically. After digging into this issue for a while, the following code does exactly what I want and is believed to be the most optimized to the best of my knowledge.

```
[ -z "$TMUX"  ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session && exit;}
```

Note this line should be the first line in you bashrc file to make sure it is loaded first. We can't put an "exec" call in front of "tmux attach" because after the exec replaces the bash process with the tmux one, the connection will be closed even if there are no sessions to attach to. Therefore we need an "exit" call to terminate the connection after we detach or exit from the attached sessions. But putting an "exec" in front the new-session command is fine as that's the last command to be executed.

Comment: This is the one that works best for me - some of the others reattach to tmux but start a new window every time I login.

Comment: @huangzonghao This worked fine for me for a day or so, then I started to get: 

no sessions.
server exited unexpectedly.
Connection to db-server closed.

Comment: @henrikstroem did you happen to make some modification to the shell running on the machine? Because "no session" error seems to be triggered by running `tmux attach` without a existing tmux session. However if the `[ -z "$TMUX" ]` is evaluated correctly, `tmux attach` should not be called if there were no tmux sessions.

Comment: @huangzonghao No, it's actually the only thing in the `.profile` file (it's an ash shell on Alpine).

Comment: @henrikstroem well in that case I am not familiar with the shell your are using. my guess is that the `server exited unexpectedly` might be the one causing the problem. look into that may be giving more hints to the issue. To stay in connection and avoid `Connection to db-server closed`, just remove the `exit` command from the line.

Comment: @huangzonghao Yes, that was also my work-around until I figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Append following **line of code** to the end of `.bashrc`,

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```

Answer (score 3):

I just made it a keyboard shortcut (in Linux Mint not Ubuntu; so I'm not sure if it is this easy)...

---

[image: custom shortcut for tmux terminal]

---

It might be hard to see, but the *custom shortcut* is `gnome-terminal --window --maximize -e tmux`. This starts a new `gnome-terminal` window maximized and then `exec`utes `tmux` for you.

I additionally have another *custom shortcut* that starts a "normal" `gnome-terminal` maximized (it's the same without the `-e tmux`).

I feel this is the best way because you can start whatever terminal whatever way you want and is the most customizable way.

Answer (score 3):

I started with this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Bash and enhanced it to reclaim detached sessions and make new ones if all sessions were already attached

```
# .bashrc

case $- in
    *i*)
    if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
        if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [[ -z $TMUX ]]; then
          if tmux ls 2> /dev/null | grep -q -v attached; then
            exec tmux attach -t $(tmux ls 2> /dev/null | grep -v attached | head -1 | cut -d : -f 1)
          else
            exec tmux
          fi
        fi
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: remove the grep and params to "tmux attach" if you always want to attach (from multiple machines at the same time)

Answer (score 2):

To enable tmux for login and ssh sessions, you can add this to the end of your .bashrc:

```
# enable tmux at login
PNAME="$(ps -o comm= $PPID)";
if [ $PNAME == "login" ] || [ $PNAME == "sshd" ] ; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

This script looks for the parent process of the bash shell. If bash was started from logging in or from ssh, it will execute tmux. If you want this to work with a GUI terminal, you can add that in there as well. For example, if you want to start tmux automatically when you start Ubuntu's standard `gnome-terminal`, you would use this:

```
PNAME="$(ps -o comm= $PPID)";
if [ $PNAME == "login" ] || [ $PNAME == "sshd" ] || [ $PNAME == "gnome-terminal" ] ; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

I've tested the above on Live Ubuntu Desktop and I was able to log in afterwards. This should not break the GUI login unless it invokes the login command to log in. I am not aware of a linux GUI that does this.

Comment: that parent process check is necessary, otherwise it results with a login-loop as in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Within xfce4 (I'm running Fedora 24 XFCE spin, it's great), I've found the simplest solution is to edit panel shortcuts to so they run:

xfce4-terminal -e tmux

This same command can be used to replace the Keyboard Application Shortcut.

I had previously inserted an if statement into my .bashrc, but it caused login to fail (loop back to the login box whenever a correct password was entered).

The command for Thunar's Open Terminal Here command differs slightly. To change that goto:

Thunar > Edit > Configure Custom Actions... > Open Terminal Here > Edit button, and replace:

exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator

with: xfce4-terminal --working-directory %f -e tmux

Comment: Thank you for this! You saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner that also makes sure the terminal type is set correctly for 256 colors:

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color && exec tmux
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding

```
# If not running interactively, do not do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

to your .bashrc. It also works for zsh.

Taken from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_with_default_session_layout