# Shortcut for opening tmux terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux, gnome-terminal

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. Very often, the first thing I do when starting to work on a new task is open a new terminal with the shortcut `Ctrl - Alt - T` and then type `tmux`.

I would like to skip the typing of `tmux`. I found several solutions in which one appends the bashrc, but it sounds like this may break the system, which frightens me (see the warning in the second link):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/how-can-i-set-my-default-shell-to-start-up-tmux

[How can I make TMUX be active whenever I start a new shell session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068965/how-can-i-make-tmux-be-active-whenever-i-start-a-new-shell-session)

How may I safely open a new terminal with tmux using a shortcut, without risking to damage my system?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152028/10248678

Comment: Ok, not very clear what to do in details from this. By the way, why downvote?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but I know several people around me who were wondering how to do this - and this is the reason why I posted this question + answer. I agree that for a bash / ubuntu advanced user this is a trivial question, but this may be useful for people with less experience who are not too familiar with personalized shortcuts and command line tweaks.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information ;) Sometimes get a bit sad when seeing downvote without explanation, but so it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to set up a new shortcut. In Ubuntu 16.04, I can:

- open the **Keyboard** utility,
- go to **Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts**,
- create a new shortcut named **TmuxTerminal**, which launch the command `gnome-terminal -e "tmux new"`, and bind it to for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is my default terminal shortcut which I still want to use now and then, and TMux...).

This way I can launch a tmux terminal by shortcut, without taking the risk of damaging my system. similar tweaks are certainly possible on other versions of Ubuntu / distros.