# Can one configure Tmux to load ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: linux, tmux

Right now, when I log in to Tmux, only `~/.bash_profile` gets loaded.

I'd like `~/.bashrc` to get called instead.

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.bashrc/.profile is not loaded on new tmux session (or window) -- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652126/bashrc-profile-is-not-loaded-on-new-tmux-session-or-window-why)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is not related to `tmux`. To solve it make sure to add `source ~/.bashrc` to `.bash_profile` and that's it.

You can learn more about `bash` initialization and which files it loads and in which order here: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization#bash

As you can see `.bashrc` is not even on the list when bash is started in login mode, that's why we source it from the file (`.bash_profile`) that is on the list.

Comment: The Invocation section of the man page would be a better reference to which files are used on startup.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, i have already my `.bash_profile` sourcing my `.bashrc` and tmux isn't reading it

Answer (score 9):

You can fix that at the `tmux` level by explicitly setting the default shell command:

```
tmux set-option default-command "/bin/bash"
```

From the `tmux` manual (emphasis mine):

> ```
>          default-command shell-command
>                  Set the command used for new windows (if not specified
>                  when the window is created) to shell-command, which may
>                  be any sh(1) command.  The default is an empty string,
>                  which instructs tmux to create a **login shell** using the
>                  value of the default-shell option.
>          default-shell path
>                  Specify the default shell.  This is used as the login
>                  shell for new windows when the default-command option is
>                  set to empty, and must be the full path of the exe‐
>                  cutable.  When started tmux tries to set a default value
>                  from the first suitable of the SHELL environment vari‐
>                  able, the shell returned by getpwuid(3), or /bin/sh.
>                  This option should be configured when tmux is used as a
>                  login shell.
> ```

As explained by Chepner in a comment below:

> `default-shell` defaults to your preferred login shell;
>   `default-command` defaults to starting a login instance, effectively
>   `$SHELL -l`

... and in the case of Bash, a *login* shell doesn't read `~/.bashrc`. By overriding the value of `default-command`, we can now force `tmux` to create a *non-login* shell instead.

Comment: You don't need the `-i` to start an interactive shell in this case, since the shell's standard input/error will be tied to a (pseudo)terminal.

Comment: @chepner Indeed; fixed in the answer.
But I don't understand then why setting explicitly the default command to "/bin/bash" works but if I let the defaults it don't. Even while both my $SHELL and `passwd` entry are set to `/bin/bash`. According to the relevant part of the man quoted in my answer, it shouldn't make any difference. Or did I missed something?

Comment: `default-shell` defaults to your preferred login shell; `default-command` defaults to starting a login instance, effectively `$SHELL -l`.

Comment: Starting tmux with it in the command line does not work in XUbuntu 18.04 LTS & tmux 2.6. Isn't it meant to run in the command line?