# difference between /anaconda3/bin/conda and /anaconda3/condabin/conda

Tags: anaconda, tmux

inside shell when

```
which conda
```

I get

```
/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

while inside tmux I get

```
/anaconda3/condabin/conda
```

Anyone knows the difference or something wrong with my config?

Comment: I'd guess it probably has to do with tmux sessions not sourcing `.bashrc` (or whatever shell you have). E.g., see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652126/bashrc-profile-is-not-loaded-on-new-tmux-session-or-window-why).

Comment: @merv Now, I reinstalled anaconda3. Both shell(I use iTerm) and tmux will give me /anaconda3/condabin/conda. I am sure I source .bashrc and .bash_profile manually. I found a similar case [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/69954). But still no idea how to fix it. Any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just to address what the primary question: Conda sets up `condabin` as a directory to always keep on PATH primarily so that the `conda` command can be available when **base** is not activated.

When you have **base** activated, running `which conda` will find `bin/conda` first on PATH; any other time `condabin/conda` will be found.

The issue in OP indicates the `tmux` session is not activating the **base** environment.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found an answer [here](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm/issues/67#issuecomment-319561401) that worked for me. Basically as @shouya said there, this problem is because tmux's `run-shell` command runs a shell which doesn't read from user configs, thus tmux installed in /usr/local/bin will not be found. And best solution is to insert the following line:

```
set-environment -g PATH "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"
```

before the first `run-shell/run` command in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, and leave everything else untouched.
Then reload `~/.tmux.conf` file by

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```