# Understanding miniconda condabin vs bin

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, virtual-environment

My question is similar to [difference between /anaconda3/bin/conda and /anaconda3/condabin/conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420701/difference-between-anaconda3-bin-conda-and-anaconda3-condabin-conda), and the answer provided there simply solves the OP worries without explanation.
Assuming I have `base` and created `test` conda environments. In `base`

```
which conda
```

gives  `/home/user/miniconda3/bin/conda`, totally fine with that. However, in `test`

```
which conda
```

gives `/home/user/miniconda3/condabin/conda`. I was expecting to get `/home/user/miniconda3/envs/test/bin/conda` to be sure I am using conda from the `test` environment.
Any detailed explanations to this, and what `condabin` means exactly?

Comment: This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone explain this function/library to me" or "provide a tutorial or information on how this works" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: I answered the actual question on the other one - closing this as duplicate.

Comment: @itprorh66 seems like a perfectly sensible question to me, certainly not deserving the downvote someone gave. It is well-formulated, contrasts the actual and expected behavior, and linked a related thread that lacked an adequate explanation.

Comment: @merv thanks for the rescue and for answering my question. I actually wanted to request further explanation in the comment section of the original question but do not have enough reputation; and here am I being down-voted, possibly due to low reputation. The world is not for the less privileged, I guess 

Comment: @merv quoting from your answer "any other time `condabin/conda` will be found". How do I ensure my conda refers to `test` environment, in my case, when it is activated and `condabin` is returned.  I work with multiple pytorch environments and need to ensure I do not install certain modules with conda outside their respective enviromnets.    BTW, again I do not have enough reputation to comment on the other question.

Comment: @Toonia I think there is confusion. The `condabin/conda` will act on the active environment by default - you do not (and really should not) have the `conda` package install in any other environment. I recommend always using a `--name,-n` argument to guarantee Conda knows what environment to operate on irrespective of the active one. I.e., `conda install -n test torchvision`.

Comment: @merv perfect, thanks for your help. Knowing that `condabin/conda` defaults to the active environment clears up everything for me.