# How does micromamba work and what is "condabin?"

Tags: anaconda, conda, mamba

After installing micromamba (same with any flavor of conda), when my .bashrc loads I have an entry in my path like:

`/home/users/balter/micromamba/condabin`

It would be natural to think that this is the directory where one would find the conda executable, but  not so:

```bash
balter@exahead1:~$ which micromamba
/usr/bin/which: no micromamba in (/home/groups/chse/Code/quality_measures:/home/groups/chse/Code/exacloud_utilities:/home/users/balter/micromamba/condabin:/home/users/balter/perl5/bin:/home/exacloud/software/spack/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/ibutils/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/users/balter/usr/bin:/home/users/balter/bin)
balter@exahead1:~$ ls micromamba/
bin    compiler_compat  COPYING  envs  fonts    lib      man   pyodbc.pyi  sbin   ssl  x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
cmake  conda-meta       docs     etc   include  libexec  pkgs  README      share  var  x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
balter@exahead1:~$ find . -type d -name "condabin"
balter@exahead1:~$ conda activate
(base) balter@exahead1:~$
```

So,

1. My path contains a directory that doesn't exist.
2. I can run a command, e.g. `micromamba`, that `which` doesn't know the location of.

How does this work, and what is the purpose of `~/micromamba/condabin`?

Comment: Micromamba is not just another Conda. Very different beast.

Comment: I do know that. However this aspect applies to both. Feel free to base your answer on either.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75874698/570918 I.e., some symlinks and entry points are created there to always keep essential software on PATH when **base** isn’t activated.

Comment: @merv -- some similarities. But your answer there states "Conda sets up condabin as a directory to always keep on PATH primarily so that the conda command can be available when base is not activated." However, the directory `.../condabin` DOES NOT exist whether or not I have micromamba activated. So how does it ensure "that the conda command can be available when base is not activated." And still, how can I user the command `micromamba activate` when the `micromamba` executable doesn't even exist according to `which`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can run a command, e.g. `micromamba`, that `which` doesn't know the location of.

This is because you probably have the mamba initialize block somewhere in your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` if on Windows or macOS) which looks something like this:

```bash
# >>> mamba initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'mamba init' !!
export MAMBA_EXE="/opt/homebrew/bin/micromamba";
export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX="/Users/pavel/micromamba";
__mamba_setup="$("$MAMBA_EXE" shell hook --shell bash --prefix "$MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX" 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__mamba_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/pavel/micromamba/etc/profile.d/micromamba.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/pavel/micromamba/etc/profile.d/micromamba.sh"
    else
        export  PATH="/Users/pavel/micromamba/bin:$PATH"  # extra space after export prevents interference from conda init
    fi
fi
unset __mamba_setup
# <<< mamba initialize <<<
```

Here, `"$MAMBA_EXE" shell hook --shell bash --prefix "$MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX"` gets called where the function `micromamba` is defined.

So you can call `micromamba` activate even if `micromamba` is not in `$PATH` because it is a function. If you call `type micromamba` you should get the function definition

```bash
micromamba() {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        activate|deactivate)
            __mamba_activate "$@"
            ;;
        install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
            __mamba_exe "$@" || \return
            __mamba_reactivate
            ;;
        self-update)
            __mamba_exe "$@" || \return

            # remove leftover backup file on Windows
            if [ -f "$MAMBA_EXE.bkup" ]; then
                rm -f $MAMBA_EXE.bkup
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            __mamba_exe "$@"
            ;;
    esac
}
```

> what is the purpose of ~/micromamba/condabin?

The `condabin` directory is for the shell initialization scripts for `powershell` and `cmd.exe`. [Here](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/blob/15f6b6e6062ce33a4562ef7003b90c42adfd329a/micromamba/tests/test_activation.py#L428-L447) you can see which shell initialization scripts should lie where. `bash` and `zsh` initialization scripts are in `~/micromamba/etc/profile.d/` and `cmd.exe` as well as `powershell` are in `~/micromamba/condabin/`.